# Reading one variable from a text file as a function of two other variables in the same file in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a data file which is of similar form as the following sample file:

```
Time     H         T

 0       1        100  
 0       2        200  
 0       3        300  
 0       4        400  
 0       5        500  
10       1        600  
10       2        700  
10       3        800  
10       4        900  
10       5        101  
20       1        102  
20       2        103  
20       3        104   
20       4        105  
20       5        106
```

This is how the data appears in the text file. I need to read the third column as a function of the first two columns i.e., I need to read `time(1) =0`, `time(2) = 10`, `time(3) = 20` and `H(1) = 1`, `H(2) = 2......,H(5) = 5` and `T(2,1) = 600`, `T(1,1) = 100` etc.

Can someone please help me with some hints? Thank you.

**UPDATED**

I was working on the program, I ended up with a logic, which did what I wanted to do.The following program reads the data (given above), makes some sense out of it, and in the end creates a two dimensional array of the variable T1. It assigns indices 1,2 and 3 to time and 1,2,3,4,5 to H, so that `T(i,j)` corresponds to the value of T1 at `time = i`, `H = j`. So if you know the indices then you can find any value of T1.

But it would have been better if I could ask for the value of T for `time = 20` and `H = 5`, without bothering about the indices. Please give suggestions

```
    Program Sort

    IMPLICIT NONE

        Real, Dimension(20)      :: time, H, T

        Real, Dimension(20)       :: time1
        Real, Dimension(20)       :: H1
        Real, Dimension(20,20)    :: T1

        Integer                   :: i, j, n, k, m, l

        Open(1,file = "trial-data.dat")

        Do i = 1, 20

100      Continue

           Read(1, *, err = 100, end = 101) time(i), H(i), T(i)
           k = i

        Enddo

101     Continue

        m = 1

       Do i = 1, k-1

        If( time(i+1) .eq. time(i)) then
           time1(m) = time(i)
          else if ( time(i+1) .ne. time(i)) then
            m = m + 1
            time1(m) = time(i+1) 
         Endif

       Enddo

       n = 0

       Do i = 1, k

         If (H(i+1) .eq. H(1)) then

           n = i 
    
           Exit

        Endif

       Enddo

       Do i = 1, n

         H1(i) = H(i)

       Enddo

       l = 0

       Do i = 1, m
         Do j = 1, n
          T1(i,j) = T(j+l)
         Enddo
        l = l+5
      Enddo

       Do i = 1, m
         Do j = 1, n

          Print*, T1(i,j)

         Enddo
       Enddo

    End Program Sort
```

Comment: First, write a wee bit of code to ignore the headers in the input file.  Next, write another line of code to read a line with 3 integer values.  Then write a line of code to insert the values into the array `T` in line with your rules.  Repeat these last two steps until you have reached the end of the input file.  For more than such hints, post your own best attempt and we'll help finish it.

Comment: We really have many similar questions with code samples already. Please look there first. We have answers how to skip the header, we have answers about how to read data in columns.

Comment: Please give us also some comments about the code you posted. What happens when you compile it? What happens when you run it? Any error messages? Copy them. Wrong results? Show them. See also [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thank you so much for your reply. I updated my question by adding the code I was working on. (just finished). It is not very elegant, but it served my purpose in a crude way. If I know the indices I can get the value of T1. It will be nice if I could just straightaway ask for the T1 value for any given time and H. Any suggestions regarding the code will be much appreciated. Please reply in kindness, I am not very good at coding.

Comment: To get a value for any given time you will have to search your array. And possibly interpolate, if you want some time in between your data points.

Answer (score 0):

You can just read all three values from a simple read statement like this:

```
   integer x,y,z

   read(5,*) x,y,z
```

and it should read all 3 values from each line.